# How to type a function so that its return type matches that of an array that is being returned?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, union-types

This is very hard to describe property in the title, so here is an example: I have a function that should return an array with two items:

```
const calc = () => Math.random();

const myFunc = () => ([calc(), 'string']);
```

So that the first item in the array is always the return type of the `calc` function, and the second is always a string.

When I run this, the type inferred for `myFunc` becomes `(number | string)[]`:

[image]

Instead, I want the type to be `[number, string]` so I can deconstruct like so:

```
const [calcResult, str] = myFunc();
```

...and both items will be typed correctly.

Normally, I would just explicitly give `myFunc` a return type:

```
const myFunc = (): [number, string] => ([calc(), 'string']);
```

then I get what I want:

[image]

The tricky part is that I can't just add the hard coded return type to `myFunc`  because the type returned by `calc()` in my real code is very complex (doesn't even show up completely when I use the IDE's inference display feature) and can easily change over time. So **I want to let it continue to be inferred**, while keeping the fixed structure of returned type match the exact array I'm returning so I can use deconstruction with it.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the answer... I needed the `typeof` keyword to refer to the inferred type. So, I can do:

```
const calc = () => Math.random();

const myFunc = () => {
    const result = calc();

    return [result, 'string'] as [typeof result, string];
};
```

Which yields the correct type:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want, but if I execute your code I get this

```
const calc = () => Math.random();
const myFunc = () => ([calc(), 'string']);
myFunc()

-> RESULT [0.2612262266408696, "string"]
```

That is what you expected?

Comment: The result is correct, but the type of the result is not... if you assign the result of myFunc to a variable, it will be typed as `(string | number)[]`, so... its an array that can have string or number in any position. Instead, I want an array that can only have a number on the first position, and a string on the second (so I can deconstruct the items correctly). The type should be `[string, number]`. I can do this by hard coding the type, but since `calc()`'s return type is very complex I would like to keep it inferred. I'll add more details to the question.

Comment: I added more details to the question. The result works either way... It's a typing problem. Thank you for looking into it!